# Python. Список№1 добавить в список№2, но список№1 должен быть как один элемент

Tags: python, list

list1 = [1, 2, 3] 
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

Как объединить два списка, что бы получить такой результат?

out: [1, 2, 3, list2]

Спасибо.

Comment: смотря как вы понимаете один элемент: 
list1.append(list2) или list1 = list1+ list2

Comment: нет. .append, .extend, .insert не подходят. должно быть именно [1, 2, 3, list2]

Comment: Невозможно получить [1, 2, 3, list2]. Разберитесь с заданием.

Comment: @ArsRem append и добавляет список как один элемент. Все его элементы выводятся, потому что именно так выводятся списки. Это именно вопрос отображения, а не вопрос внутренней структуры. Вы же когда просто список выводите, не ожидаете, что программа напечатает вам только его имя?

Answer (score 0):

`Python 3.6.9`

Вариант 1 (изменять исходный список)

```
>>> list1.append(list2)
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Вариант 2 (не изменять исходный список)

```
>>> list3 = list1 + [list2]
>>> list3
[1, 2, 3, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Вариант 3 (не изменять исходный список)

```
>>> list4 = [*list1, list2]
>>> list4
[1, 2, 3, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: нет. .append, .extend, .insert не подходят. должно быть именно [1, 2, 3, list2]

Comment: @ArsRem Тогда я вообще ничего не понял. Цель, получить список из четырех элементов. Первый элемент - 1 (тип `int`), потом 2, тоже `int`, затем 3, снова `int` <- они берутся из списка №1. А четвертый элемент - что это такое должно быть и какого типа и как список №2 должен к этому относиться? И чего вообще хочется добиться?

Comment: Типы данных там не важны. необходимо в список№1 [1,2,3] добавить список№2 [a,b,c], но таким образом чтобы получилось не [1,2,3,a,b,c] , а получилось [1,2,3,список№2]. Грубо говоря, чтоб список№2 в не распакованном виде попадал в список№1

Comment: @ArsRem В примерах из ответа получается [1, 2, 3, ['a', 'b', 'c']] - четвертый элемент - список внутри списка, нераспакованный, что именно не так? Тогда вам первый вариант, чтобы первый список поменялся и включил в себя второй в качестве последнего элемента.

Comment: [1, 2, 3, ['a', 'b', 'c']] - в этом примере - показаны все элементы всех списков.
[1, 2, 3, list2]  - нужно чтоб имело такой вид

Comment: Это маразм, и я не понимаю зачем Вам это нужно но:
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = ["a","b","c"]
list1.append("list2")

Comment: про маразм абсолютно согласен. но это тестовое задание.. уже  всю голову сломал

Comment: Ни один адекватный тест не попросит добавить имя переменной в список

Comment: Тут какое-то недопонимание...

Comment: Согласен с Вами, более вероятен Ваш @mrEvgenX первый ответ

Comment: @mrEvgenX должны быть добавлены  не элементы списка  list2, а список list2 как один элемент - [1,2,3,list2]

Comment: Разберитесь с вопросом и возвращайтесь. Вам уже сказали как добавить список "как один элемент", но вас это не устраивает.